# Flood Fill method crashing with bad access error any ideas?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My Flood fill method is crashing with bad access error and i can't find the error any ideas please?

When i start my app I can paint little objects just fine but when i want to use flood fill like a paint bucket to fill bigger objects with paint it just crashes with BAD ACCESS error.

Im a noob and i tried a lot of things and the number of recursion went up but its still crashing. 
Im using ARC with this app.

```
-(void)paintingBucket:(int)point point2:(int)point2 width:(int)width colorAtPoint:(UIColor *)color {

int offset = 0;
int x = point;
int y = point2;
if (point<1025 && point2<705) {

offset = 4*((width*round(y))+round(x));

int alpha = data[offset];
int red = data[offset + 1];
int green = data[offset + 2];
int blue = data[offset + 3];
color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(green/255.0f) green:(red/255.0f) blue:(alpha/255.0f) alpha:(blue/255.0f)];

   if ([color1 isEqual: color] ) {

        color3 = self.currentColor ;
        CGFloat r,g,b,a;
        [color3 getRed:&r green:&g blue: &b alpha: &a];
        int reda = (int)(255.0 * r);
        int greena = (int)(255.0 * g);
        int bluea = (int)(255.0 * b);
        int alphaa = (int)(255.0 * a);
       // NSLog(@" red: %u green: %u blue: %u alpha: %u", reda, greena, bluea, alphaa);

        data[offset + 3] = alphaa;
        data[offset + 2] = reda;
        data[offset + 1] = greena;
        data[offset] = bluea;

        [self paintingBucket:x+1 point2:y  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
        [self paintingBucket:x point2:y+1  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
        [self paintingBucket:x-1 point2:y  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
        [self paintingBucket:x point2:y-1  width:width colorAtPoint:color];

            }

        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
Only information i get when it crashes is this "0x995d7d5f:  calll  0x995d7d64                ; szone_malloc_should_clear + 14"

i understand that there is some memory problem but i cant identify it i resolve it.
As i said im a noob to objective c so any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe you should look for any crash information in the console, and figure out where the debugger stack display says the problem occurred.  Then include that info in your post.

Comment: You are writing to a data[] array. Maybe that's too small.

Comment: i dont think so because data array is representing bitmap pixels and there are a lot more of pixels than the number of iterations i reach.

Comment: You get more error cause information than what you posted.  You need to learn how to find and interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

It is almost certainly a stack overflow. When you flood-fill an area recursively, the number of items on the stack equals the length of the fronteer, which may get quite long for larger areas.

You should replace your recursive approach with a queue-based one to fix this problem.

Comment: can you give me an example how to do that please? or a link with some pointers to the solution of the problem?

Comment: @lost4ever Sure - take a look at the ["alternative implementations" section on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations), they have easy-to-follow pseudocode of queue or explicit stack based approaches.

Comment: i tried implementing this but had no luck, and tried some other things its still crashing, can you help me with some example code please?

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
int x = point;
int y = point2;

if (point<1025 && point2<705) 
{
...
```

but you are subtracting from x and y and not checking whether they are > 0

```
    [self paintingBucket:x-1 point2:y  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
    [self paintingBucket:x point2:y-1  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
```

this could be the cause of the overflow since the recursion will not stop for negative values.

Comment: tried adding "...&& (x>0 && y>0)" i didnt help at all. but thanks for the suggestion anyway.